# Создание админки на yii framework

Tags: php, yii

Актуален ли данный способ?

http://habrahabr.ru/post/117457/

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Актуально. Все что касается Yii 1.1 будет актуально еще года 2.